# Users who install and uninstall immediately are counted in Google Play app's downloads?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

When a user downloads an app from Google Play, app's download counter is increased no matter if the user uninstalls the app immediately?

Is there a minimum of time the app must be on the device?

or a minimum of use (e.g. it must be opened at least once)?

Answer (score 1):

> *When a user downloads an app from Google Play, app's download counter is increased no matter if the user uninstalls the app immediately?* - **Yes**
>
> *Is there a minimum of time the app must be on the device?
> or a minimum of use?* - **No**

- From Google [developer console help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) , it appears that both are *unrelated* and counted as discrete events. For instance, *Daily Statistics* on the console are defined as below . There is *no* mention of *time* it stays installed or *use*

> **Daily installs by user:** Unique users who installed the app on one or more of their devices for the first time in the past day
>
> **Daily uninstalls by user:** Unique users who uninstalled the app from all of their devices in the past day

- From [Quora - How does the downloads count for an app in the Google Play Store work](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-downloads-count-for-an-app-in-the-Google-Play-Store-work), developer Sophia Wang clarifies that installing and uninstalling will not change the number of downloads, which further supports that these two events are not connected in any way for statistics
- [Billions: How exactly do Apple and Google count app downloads?](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/05/16/billions-how-exactly-do-apple-and-google-count-app-downloads/) says "
  Both Apple and Google tabulate unique downloads of apps per user account. This means that they count only one download of an app no matter how many devices that you install that app on after you purchase it"

Comment: Would welcome additions / corrections from developers

Comment: Quora shouldn't be used as a definitive source. It's just people providing their own answers which are often only best guesses. If you look, you'll notice there's another answer on the same Quora question that says each individual device is counted, which contradicts your thenextweb source.

Comment: @Patrick: I am aware and normally avoid. Quoted here as a developer claiming this . As you observed, other sources support